# HTML CSS - "Fill" a div up with different sized blocks

Tags: html, css, image

I have a division which I'm trying to fill up with 50x50 tiles.

Some tiles are 100x50, and some are 50x100.

When I just fill up the div with 50x50, everything fits very snugly.

When I try to put in 50x100 or 100x500, it seems like some spaces get blocked.

How would I make this so the tiles will not skip blank spaces?

**Example**

[image]

Image blocks are inserted sequentially

Comment: You've not posted any code, but I assume you're floating your `div`s. Apart from using absolute positioning, and calculating the positions yourself, I cannot think of any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the colspan & rowspan correctly, this is the result:

[image]

```html
   <table style="table-layout:fixed;border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;"><tbody><tr>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">1</td>

<td rowspan="2" colspan="0" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">2</td>

<td rowspan="1" colspan="-1" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">3</td>

<td rowspan="1" colspan="-2" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">4</td>

<td rowspan="1" colspan="-3" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">5</td>



</tr><tr>
<td rowspan="0" colspan="1" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">6</td>

<td rowspan="0" colspan="0" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">7</td>

<td rowspan="0" colspan="-1" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">8</td>

<td rowspan="0" colspan="-2" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">9</td>



</tr><tr>
<td rowspan="-1" colspan="1" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">10</td>

<td rowspan="-1" colspan="0" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">11</td>

<td rowspan="-1" colspan="2" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">12</td>

<td rowspan="-1" colspan="-2" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid grey;text-color:red;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;background-color:red;">13</td>


</tr>
</tbody></table>
```